# Setting Zend Soap Client Content Type

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, soap-client

I seem to be getting the following error when making a call using the Zend SOAP Client.

"Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/ISendAPI/GetExchangeRateList"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'."

Is there any way I can set the content type, couldn't really find anything in the documenation

THANKS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Soap Client Version to e.g. 1.1?

`$this->_soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_1);`

Seems to be a bit buggy:
http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5286